# How can I make image thumbnails load faster from a network drive in order to cull them?

Tags: sorting, thumbnails, network-drive, image-file

I need to sort through ~80,000 pictures, most of which are important but a good few are photos are useless  because the lens was covered (black photos), or they were simply taken by accident and are blurry pictures of the ground. I have been scrolling through in file explorer and glancing over thumbnails for each picture and deleting the ones that are clearly useless, usually just black pictures. The problem is that the pictures themselves are on a Network drive and the thumbnails often don't load at all, and when they do it is very slow. I do not mind scrolling through and looking at each thumbnail, I just need them to load faster.

Is there either A) a way to make these thumbnails load faster in windows file explorer from this remote drive or B) another program I could open up the drive in that would be able to load the thumbnails faster? I am also open to any other ways

I have tried opening the drive through chrome, but this does not display the thumbnails and also will not allow me to delete the individual pictures one by one.